# Is there such a thing as "Injective Relief" (as a legal term)?

Tags: meaning, orthography, legalese

I was recently given a nondisclosure agreement to sign.  On the form it stated that the company may seek "injective relief" as needed in order to enforce the agreement.  Now, I'm quite familiar with the concept of "injunctive relief."  Googling around I did find quite a few places where "injective relief" is used, but I couldn't find anything that looked like a proper legal definition for it.  (Also it's waaaaay less common than "injunctive relief".)

So I ask those who may have better google-fu or more in-depth legalese knowledge, is this just a misspelling on the company's part, or can they shoot me up with truth serum if the need arises?

Comment: Unless you're considering a shot of morphine, there is no injective relief in contract law.

Comment: My father was an attorney, and I can recall several malapropisms in the documents he worked with, including the use of "antinuptial agreement" when "antenuptial agreement" was intended.  Surprisingly, attorneys are, as a rule, not terribly careful with the language, and it is incredibly common for such an error to be copied from one document to another to another (even before the computer era).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost certainly a typo that has propagated wildly, probably thanks to a popular word processing spell-checker. I have never heard of injective relief. Also, most NDA forms you'll ever see are funny little mashups, often used by small companies who simply assume they're legally accurate and binding.